# Eclipse find file in Navigator (not Find Resource)

Tags: eclipse

I remember once setting a shortcut to find a file and focus on it within Eclipse's Navigator view (or some other explorer view). It wasn't a pre-defined shortcut, but one I assigned to action I found in keyboard bindings.

Note this is not Find Resource (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) - I do not want to open the file, just focus on it in a navigator/explorer view so that I can perform operations on it (SVN, rename, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't what I remember, but it is close enough.

- Find Resource (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
- Search for the file.
- At the bottom of the `Open Resource` dialog, select `Show In > Project Explorer`.

It lets me see/act upon a file in navigator/explorer view without opening the file, which is what I wanted.

I remember being able to do that in one action. Perhaps it was a long forgotten plugin.

Comment: You can use this command even file is not open it will work from "Open Resource" dialog and from search view also. You  need to select(not open) that file in dialog/Search view. Then use command ALT+SHIFT+W+N.

Comment: Am marking my own answer as correct here, because I feel it is closest to what I wanted out of all the other answers, even though the other answers are good to know and my own answer still isn't exactly what I remembered being able to do.

Answer (score 3):

If file is open then use

```
ALT+SHIFT+W+N
```

It will select file in navigator. If you want to select file in "Package Explorer" use

```
ALT+SHIFT+W+P
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

[image: File Search in Eclipse]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> ------> file search ------------> file name pattern (like `index.jsp`)

Search tab appears beside server tab.
You can perform all `SVN` operations on it. Hierarchy view appears with exact file name and extension.

Comment: It's close, but it wasn't what I remember being able to do: an action that will focus on the result in one of the Explorer/Navigator views. From the search results pane, you cannot do all file-related operations. Although you can do SVN operations, you can't move, delete, rename etc.

Comment: just click on index.jsp and press alt+shift+W (or right click on index.jsp and then showin ) ----> click on navigator